# Gatling file upload with jsf

Tags: jsf, gatling

I have recorded request with gatling

```
val addFile = exec(jsfPost("request_1", "/mypages/edit/Publication/247307/default?rf_fu_uid=0.7920034590642899")
  .headers(headers_4)
  .header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
  /* some form params */
  .bodyPart(ByteArrayBodyPart("ioWizardView:ioWizardForm:publ_has_file_PUBL_has_FILE", bytes)
  .contentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet").fileName("postgre_50_juel.xlsx").charset("iso-8859-1"))
  .asFormUrlEncoded)
```

I try to send it to server, but on server side I have error

```
--hXlZi0Ndw092_ZlvrWTUksxrmiCKDIOma
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ioWizardView:ioWizardForm:publ_has_file_PUBL_has_FILE";
filename="postgre_50_juel.xlsx"
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
PK     ! b  ?    h^[Content_Types].xml ?    (?
java.io.CharConversionException: isHexDigit
```

Answer (score 0):

"java.io.CharConversionException: isHexDigit" means that the bytes you're passing can't be properly decoded with the charset you set (""iso-8859-1"").

You probably used another encoding when you computed the "bytes" that you pass.

If you're not computing the upload file on the fly, you'd better use a RawFileBody instead of a ByteArrayBodyPart.

Comment: When I try RawFileBody I have the same issue

Comment: Are you sure that your file uses "ISO-8859-1" encoding?